# read a doc and rewrite with Apache POI ,but fail to open with office

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to modify a doc with Apache POI in Java.

At first the test.doc cannot be read with a exception raised up :

"org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NotOLE2FileException: Invalid header signature; read 0x6576206C6D783F3C, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0 - Your file appears not to be a valid OLE2 document
"

So I saved the doc as "word 97 - 03" format,and then POI can read the doc properly.

**But when I try to rewrite the content to a new file with nothing changed, the file output.doc cannot be opened by MS Office.**

When I make a new doc myself with MS Office, the POI works well, everything goes right.

So the problem is "test.doc".

The test.doc is generated by some sort of a program which I can't access the code,so I don't know what goes wrong.

My question is :

**1.As test.doc can be read by MS Office why can't POI without saving as a new format doc?
2.As the POI can read the doc, why it cannot write back to a new file(MS Office can't open)?**

Here is my code:

```
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream("test.doc");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    POIFSFileSystem pfs = null;
    try {
        pfs = new POIFSFileSystem(fis);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    HWPFDocument hwdf = null;
    try {
        hwdf = new HWPFDocument(pfs);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("output.doc"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        hwdf.write(fos);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {

    }

    try {
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        fis.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        pfs.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HEX stuff read as ASCII and read little-endian converts to `<?xml ve`, which indicates that `test.doc` is some other format than actually .doc/.docx.

Word will open other data-formats gracefully sometimes, upon saving it will be saved correctly in the Word-Format.

Therefore you will need to use a hex-editor to take a look at the contents of `test.doc` and if it is really in some broken format you need to find out where it is coming from and how the creation of that file can be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the hints.After using some tools comparing the docs I found out that test.doc is actually not a pure word 03 format but a "Word 2003 XML".The bad news is There is a different format for the XML-based file formats of the Microsoft Office suite which Apache POI does not support yet.

Comment: The header is read little endian not big endian, so you need to reverse the characters - it's actually `<xml ve` at the start which is a bit clearer!